# How to add the currently edited file to project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, often I am editing a file that is not in the current project, and would like to add this file to the project. Is there an easy way to do that? The only way I've found is via right click on the project, Add/Existing Item (Shift+Alt+A), and then browse to the file I want to add in the dialog. Is there a shortcut I am missing?

Comment: vs2019, same question.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Visual Studio 2010:

Right-click on the document tab, select "Copy Full Path".

Project - Add Existing Item - Ctrl+V  - Add.